# Stop SSMS selecting brackets and quotes when double clicking to select word

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to use SSMS to develop stored procedures in SQL Server.

Typically editing involves a lot of copying and pasting of column names, table names etc.

Every text editor out there understands that double clicking will select the word.

SQL Server Management Studio likes to select the guff around it and I spend more time deleting the square brackets, etc. than I save from copying and pasting.

eg Double clicking [MyColumn] will select `[MyColumn]` when it should only select `MyColumn`.

I'm paid to develop new functionality and not paid to fight SSMS :-/

Is there a way to either turn this off, hack SSMS to disable it or replace the text editor in SSMS?

Alternatively is their a SQL server IDE that is a suitable replacement for SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no option to do this. It is SQL Server's fail-safe way of generating scripts for your objects which might contain a reserved keyword.

There is a connect item here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32671051-give-us-option-to-not-have-square-brackets-when-dr

You could create a [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) script to replace `'['` and `']'` (and do other replacements).